# what is the keyword Protocol (capital P) do in Swift

Tags: swift, foundation

Just found you can type `Protocol` directly, and its Type different from other 2 cases
[image]

actually you can try init it and got a error message that some kind of hint something
[image]

but what on earth does the `Protocol` do in Swift?

Comment: I've removed the [tag:ios] tag as this has nothing to do with iOS.  I've added the [tag:foundation] tag as that is the framework which defines the type (it isn't available in a file with no imports).

Comment: There is some good documentation on that: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

Comment: This question isn't about iOS.  It's not about `UITableViewDataSource` (yes, you'd need `UIKit` to get that, but this question isn't about any of that).  Plenty of people are watching the [tag:swift] tag.  You're not missing out on an audience by removing it (you might be missing out on an audience of Linux Swift developers, or OSX Swift devevelopers by adding it).  If, for example, you had OSX rather than iOS, I'd never look at the question.

Comment: Importantly, you *could* ask this same question from an OSX perspective showing some protocol available for `NSTableView`s.  And if that question were asked tomorrow, it'd be marked as a duplicate of this question.  Because neither question actually has anything to do with the operating system or the platform.  It has to do only with Swift, and the Foundation framework which defines the `Protocol` type.

Comment: It is not appropriate to add tags for the sole purpose of increasing traffic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Protocol` is a *class* which is defined in the Objective-C runtime
and represents an Objective-C protocol. Example:

```
let p = objc_getProtocol("NSObject")! 
print(p.dynamicType) // Output: "Protocol"
```

`objc_getProtocol` is declared as

```
/** 
 * Returns a specified protocol.
 * 
 * @param name The name of a protocol.
 * 
 * @return The protocol named \e name, or \c NULL if no protocol named \e name could be found.
 * 
 * @note This function acquires the runtime lock.
 */
@available(OSX 10.5, *)
public func objc_getProtocol(name: UnsafePointer<Int8>) -> Protocol!
```

and `Protocol` is declared as

```
// typedef Protocol is here:

// All methods of class Protocol are unavailable. 
// Use the functions in objc/runtime.h instead.

@available(OSX 10.0, *)
public class Protocol {
}
```

The underlying Objective-C definitions can be found in
[`<objc/Protocol.h>`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-680/runtime/Protocol.h)
 and 
[`<objc/runtime.h>`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-680/runtime/runtime.h).

Comment: I was about to start typing an answer.  Guess I don't have to now.  The only thing I was going to add was pointing out the most obvious use case of `Protocol` being used as a parameter type in `NSObject`'s `conformsToProtocol:` class method.

Comment: @nhgrif: But test for protocol conformance is in Swift  better done with `is` or `as?`. Also objc_getProtocol seems only to work with protocols defined in Objective-C sources, so I can't think of a real use case.

Answer (score 1):

Its a meta type that is used to define the `protocol` that you create in your app. Its just like **Type** which is used for class and structs

A metatype type refers to the type of any type, including class types, structure types, enumeration types, and protocol types.

The metatype of a class, structure, or enumeration type is the name of that type followed by .Type. The metatype of a protocol type—not the concrete type that conforms to the protocol at runtime—is the name of that protocol followed by .Protocol. For example, the metatype of the class type SomeClass is SomeClass.Type and the metatype of the protocol SomeProtocol is SomeProtocol.Protocol.

Comment: is that your guess? in that logic, `Class` is the Type for class you declared, but there is no `Class` keyword, try it yourself

Comment: In Swift, `Class` is represented by `AnyObject`.

Comment: Its not my guess. Protocol is not associated with any type when its defined. So its not a `Type`. Everything else is a `Type`. What you call Class is Type in Swift